# Class with IEnumerable property inside another IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have these classes:

```
public class InitialData
{        
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }        
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{        
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

I have a stored procedure that returns two resultsets like this

```
Id  Name
--  ----
1   John
2   Marc
3   Bruce 

Id  OrderId Number
--  ------- ------
1   1       23423
1   2       56777
2   3       44445
```

The second resultset has a relation with the Id of employee, Employee Id 3 doesn't have any order.

I want to get all orders and put them inside the Employee class without the Employee Id, 
just OrderId and Number because for each Employee I will have an Orders Property that will contains OrderId and Number so I know to which Employee belongs

In my repository I have:

```
var model = new InitialData();

using (var db = new AuditContext())
{
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[EnployeeDataSelect]";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        reader.NextResult();
        model.Employees = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<Employees>(reader).ToList();

        Now how can I put the orders under the Employees property of InitialData class filter each with the Id?
        ???
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to filter my orders for each employee and put them inside the property Orders taking in count the result I received from the stored proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have a lot of choices other than putting the employee id in your order class.

```
class Order
{ 
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;
}
...
var oc = (IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var orders = oc.Translate<Order>(reader).ToLookup(x => x.Id);
foreach(var employee in model.Employees)
    employee.Orders = orders[employee.Id].ToList();
```

If you *absolutely* don't want to add the employee id property to your `Order` class, you'd have to create another class (e.g. `EmployeeOrder`) that has an employee id property and map it back to `Order`:

```
class EmployeeOrder
{ 
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;
}
...
var orders = oc.Translate<EmployeeOrder>(reader).ToLookup(x => x.Id);
employee.Orders = orders[employee.Id].Select(x => new Order
{
    OrderId = x.OrderId,
    Number = x.Number
}.ToList();
```